# UVM: Why is get_type_name() not static?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Please consider this code...

```
virtual class SomeThing extends uvm_pkg::uvm_object;
  `uvm_object_utils(SomeThing)
  ...
endclass

class MyThing extends SomeThing#(MyTransaction);
  `uvm_object_param_utils(MyThing)

  function new(string name = "MyThing");
    super.new(name);
    `uvm_info(get_name(), {"Created a ", get_type_name(),
                           " using transactions of type: ",
                           MyTransaction::get_type_name()},  // <--
              UVM_LOW)
  endfunction
  ...
endclass: MyThing
```

My problem is tagged with the `<--`.  That's illegal because `get_type_name()` is not a static method and cannot be used with the scope resolution operator `::`.  (Both Synopsys and Cadence simulators complain similarly.)

Why isn't this method static?  It feels wrong to reach around the accessor method to read the "const static string" that holds the value I want.

Thanks!

Comment: try `MyTransaction::type_name`

Answer (score 2):

`get_type_name` isn't intended to print the name of a type. Its intention is to print the name of the type of a given object instance.

`get_type_name` is a `virtual` function. The intention behind a virtual function is to support polymorphism. If we were to have a variable of type `uvm_object` (where `get_type_name` is first defined), we could store objects of any sub-class of `uvm_object` in it. If we were to call `get_type_name` on the object, we would get the name of the object's type, without this code knowing anything about the type of this object at compile time.

Polymorphism makes it possible to write code that is generic, in that it can work with any concrete object type, as long as that type is a sub-type of something this code "understands".

Comment: Yes. Thank you Tudor timi. I do understand that this method MUST be virtual if it is to be any use at all.  I suppose my complaint is that I really want the method to be both static (allowing the scope-resolution operator) AND virtual...  Cheers!
I am (and had been) doing exactly what @Serge recommended, although it still feels a bit wrong.